# Faster addClass() for every cell in column

Tags: jquery, performance, addclass

I have a pretty big table (over 4000 rows that I need to show) and I need to add some class for every (for example) 4th cell in a row. My code can do it in about 800ms. But I need to do that 2 times (for another column and another class), so user have to wait much time.

Guys, could you please look throw my code if I miss something expensive for time? The best of my mind was that piece of code:

```
// $(td) - is a cell in header that was clicked
// index = column number to add class
var countColumns = $(td).closest("table").find("tr:last").children("td").length;
var $childrenTD = $(td).closest("table").find("tr").not("headrow").children("td");
for(var i=index; i<$childrenTD.length; i+=countColumns) {
    $($childrenTD[i]).addClass(cssClass);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks to me like you can simply do:

```
$(td).closest("table")
    .find("tr:not(.headrow) td:nth-child(" + index + ")")
    .addClass(cssClass);
```

Here you're selecting `td:nth-child(4)`, which is every `td` which is the 4th child of its parent (row).

Answer (score 0):

First off... Ben Alpert's answer is fine, and is probably acceptable.

If you still find you're seeing issues with performance or speed, I'd recommend just doing it the "old fashioned way"... with vanilla JavaScript and DOM traversal:

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VZzxd/). I've used a hybrid JQuery/vanilla-js bit of code here to skip any costly querying.

```
$('td').click(function() {
    //get all the trs in the table.
    var trs = this.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.getElementsByTagName('tr');

    for (var i = 0; i < trs.length; i++) {
        var tr = trs[i];
        if ($(tr).hasClass('headrow')) continue;
        var fourth = tr.getElementsByTagName('td')[3];        
        $(fourth).addClass('someclass');
    }
});​
```

It's not going to get a whole lot faster than that without making some custom functions to add and test for classes from the DOM, which is a pain.

**EDIT: [Here's a fiddle for a 100% vanilla JS solution](http://jsfiddle.net/VZzxd/3/)**

Here's the 100% vanilla version of it (I didn't test this in IE):

```
function bindAllElements(elements, eventName, fn) {
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        var element = elements[i];
        element.addEventListener(eventName, fn);
    }
}

function hasClass(element, className) {
    if (typeof element.className === 'undefined') return false;
    return element.className.indexOf(className) >= 0;
}

function addClass(element, className) {
    if (!hasClass(element, className)) {
        element.className += ' ' + className;
    }
}

var alltds = document.getElementsByTagName('td');

bindAllElements(alltds, 'click', function(e) {
    var td = e.target || event.srcElement;
    var table = td.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement;
    var trs = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');
    for (var i = 0; i < trs.length; i++) {
        var tr = trs[i];
        if (!hasClass(tr, 'headrow')) {
            addClass(tr.getElementsByTagName('td')[3], 'someclass');
        }
    }
});​
```

**EDIT2: Well this has been a fun challenge... [here is a jsperf](http://jsperf.com/table-dom-traversal-speed-test) showing the performance of VanillaJS/Jquery/Hybrid.**

It shows that the VanillaJS version is about twice as fast as doing it in the other suggested ways.

Comment: blesh, thanks a lot, vanilla JS is realy best of perfomance!:) 450ms is the best result :)

Comment: Thanks for the question. It was fun playing with performance.